# Call Operator() for std::shared_ptr instance

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

`CustomDynamicArray` class wraps `std::vector` and gives an access to its items by pair of indexes via overloaded operator `operator()`

```
CustomCell& CustomDynamicArray::operator()(size_t colIdx, size_t rowIdx)
```

It makes possible to address an array items a natural way:

```
CustomDynamicArray _field;
_field(x, y) = cell;
const CustomCell& currentCell = _field(x, y);
```

But since I covered my variable into `std::shared_ptr` I have an error

```
std::shared_ptr<CustomDynamicArray> _fieldPtr;
_fieldPtr(x, y) = cell; // Error! C2064 term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
const CustomCell& currentCell = _fieldPtr(x, y); // Error! C2064    term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
```

How can I fix this compile error?
Now I can see only way to use this syntax:

```
(*_newCells)(x, y) = cell;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr` is [smart pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) which behaves like raw pointers, you can't call `operator()` on the pointer directly like that. You could dereference on the `std::shared_ptr` then call the `operator()`.

```
(*_fieldPtr)(x, y) = cell;
const CustomCell& currentCell = (*_fieldPtr)(x, y);
```

Or invoke `operator()` explicitly (in ugly style).

```
_fieldPtr->operator()(x, y) = cell;
const CustomCell& currentCell = _fieldPtr->operator()(x, y);
```

Comment: Yep, I see. Is it only way?

Comment: @MalovVladimir Yes, as a smart pointer behaves exactly in the same way as a raw pointer in this way, you have to dereference it first to get its value it's pointing to.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `_fieldPtr->operator()(x, y);` ?

Comment: @Taron, I have checked. I can use _newCells->operator()(x, y) = cell; syntax, but I had overloaded operator() to simplify syntax. This function call seems a little bit clumsy, but it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to deref the pointer first:

```
(*_fieldPtr)(x, y) = cell;
const CustomCell& currentCell = (*_fieldPtr)(x, y);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, Sombrero Chicken